# Compare float values entered by users (Android)

Tags: java, android, floating-point

I have some problem with precised comparison of float values entered by users into an editable text field in my app. Here is example:

```
if ((temp>=39.0)&&(temp<=40.9)) {
    ball=ball+3;
}
```

If user enters, for example, `40.9`, the code in the loop isn't called. I am just a beginner, any help appreciated.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Please show more code and specify your question.

Comment: Pls show how you declare temp

Answer (score 1):

You should represent your literal values as `40.9f`. If you omit the 'f' the type of the literal will default to `double`.  Also check what the type is of your  `temp` variable. You didnt show how you declare `temp`.

**EDIT**

If you declared `temp` as a `Float` or a `float`, and `40.9` is a `double`, your expression `(temp <= 40.9)` is comparing a `float` to a `double`, so the compiler will automatically cast the `double` to a `float`. Converting a `double` to a `float` means halving the number of bytes of the variable, so the resulting `float` may be very different from the expected value.

Comment: temp = Float.parseFloat(Text4.getText().toString()); So, btw thanks, a lot I found solution!

Comment: @duffymo. The 40.9 and and 39.0 is wrong. The OP wants floats so he should use 40.9f and 39.0f. That is the reason why the statement doesnt work

Comment: "float" might mean "floating point number", not an explicit type of float.  You presume too much about the meaning and your correctness.

Comment: @user1901239 what was the solution? If one of the given answers helped, please accept it. If the solution was something else you can add it as another answer

Comment: So, the first way it was done, I have created epsilon, just like some gentlemens recommended, so it were working. After it I have saw this comment and just added "f" to the 40.9 and others. so it also works.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a very small margin:

```
float epsilon = 0.0001f;

if (39.0f - epsilon <= temp && temp <= 40.9f + epsilon)
{

}
```

And make sure you are parsing the user input correctly.

```
float temp = Float.parseFloat(inputField.getText());
```

Comment: to this point, there are some values which are not representable as float or double values (due to binary representation).  So arthmetic with these values is not 100% accurate.  As a result, doing these kinds of comparisons typically requires an epsilon approach as above.